# Preset button that changes checkboxes and sliders to predetermined values

Tags: java, imagej

I have some plugins in ImageJ that look at the relationships between colors (RGB or HSB) in order segment an image. They work well, but are very generic and there are quite a few checkboxes and sliders defined in the dialog.

I will soon need to go through many hundreds of images manually, but I would like to be able to look at an image and load a given preset so that I only have to fine-tune the settings. I would like to add either a series of buttons or a drop down menu that upon selection, changes the settings of all of the checkboxes/sliders to the preset values defined in that setting.

Below is how I define my dialog box, but with about 20% of the normal setting boxes/sliders.

```
    import ij.*;
    import ij.gui.*;
    import ij.process.*;
    import ij.plugin.filter.*;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.lang.Math.*;

    public class Hue_colors_filter_ implements ExtendedPlugInFilter, DialogListener {

        //private ImagePlus  imp;             // Original image
        private ImageStack sstack;          // Stack result
        private int        width;           // Width of the original image
        private int        height;          // Height of the original image
        private int        size;            // Total number of pixels
        private float[]    c1, c2, c3;      // Colour space values
        private float[]    rf, gf, bf;      // r, g, b values
        private String     colourspace;     // Colour space chosen
    private String     title;           // Name of the original image
        private String     n1, n2, n3;      // Names for every layer on the stack
    private int r,g,b; // rgb values as integers


    ImagePlus imp = null;

    private static int black = 10;
    private static boolean blackshow = true;
    private static boolean magentashow = true;

    public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
        if (imp == null) {
            IJ.noImage();
            return DONE;
        }
        if (arg.equals("about")) {
            showAbout();
            return DONE;
        }
        this.imp = imp;
        return DOES_RGB;
    }

    public int showDialog(ImagePlus imp, String command, PlugInFilterRunner pfr) {
            GenericDialog gd = new GenericDialog(command);
            gd.addSlider("Black_max: ", 0., 256., black);
                gd.addCheckbox("_Black", blackshow);
            gd.addCheckbox("_Magenta", magentashow);
                gd.addPreviewCheckbox(pfr);
            gd.addDialogListener(this);
            gd.showDialog();
            if (gd.wasCanceled()) return DONE;
            IJ.register(this.getClass());
            return IJ.setupDialog(imp, DOES_RGB);
        }

        public boolean dialogItemChanged(GenericDialog gd, AWTEvent e) {
            black = (int)gd.getNextNumber();
            blackshow = gd.getNextBoolean();
            magentashow = gd.getNextBoolean();
                return true;
        }
public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
        try{
            //do some stuff
} // end of try
        catch(Exception e){
            IJ.error("Runtime Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setNPasses (int nPasses) {
    }

    public void showAbout() {
        IJ.showMessage("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

If you can't tell I'm very much a java newb. Any help or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `setup` method receives the `ImagePlus` as a parameter. Inspect it there, then set your parameters (`black`, `blackshow`, `magentashow`, etc.) as appropriate based on your inspection. The `showDialog` method will then be called afterwards, and your code is already set up to properly pass the initial values of your parameters into the `GenericDialog`. So you should be all set.